# How to correctly remove drivers of external USB wireless network adaptor?

Tags: macos, wifi, driver

I want to completely remove the driver of a TP-Link wireless network adaptor. I can't find any tips from TP-Link's official site. Is there a right way to safely and gracefully remove?

Answer (score 10):

Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> and click the wireless icon in the menu bar at the top right of the screen. For instance, I use TP-Link so there is a TP-Link icon. Click it while holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key. You will see uninstall option there.

Answer (score 6):

I see from your comments to the posted answer of your other question ([How to remove wireless network utility icon from the menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217966/how-to-remove-wireless-network-utility-icon-from-the-menu-bar)) you have a [TL-WN822N V3](http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN822N.html) and both the [Utility package](http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN822N_V3_Utility_150910.zip) and the [Driver package](http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/soft/TL-WN822N_V3_150910.zip) come with an `Uninstall.command` to run to remove what's installed.

That would be the proper way to uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

The default location for 'drivers' (although there's not really such a thing in OS X) installed by the user is `/Library/Extensions`. I suggest looking in there for any .kext bundles which are related.

Unload the kext with `sudo kextunload /Library/Extensions/kextname.kext`, move the kext out and reboot. If everything is ok, delete the kext. If the machine kernel panics, boot into single user mode with ⌘S and move the kext back.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple
 you will find file: (Uninstall) in the package folder
just open it and put ur password then it will remove the app. for sure after restart your mac as well