# How to remove wireless network utility icon from the menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar

I installed the driver of TP-Link's wireless network adaptor, and it ships with a wireless network utility which shows an icon on the menubar.

It is invalid to click or drag this icon, and I even can't find any switches to turn it off.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried holding the Command key and removing it (drag it off)?

Comment: I tried but failed...

Comment: You say "it's invalid to click". So, it's an icon that does nothing? If you click it nothing appears?

Comment: Yes, it just sticks on the menu bar and provides nothing, no popup menu no blinking...

Comment: If you remove this software how can you connect to a wifi network? :O

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The menubar icon is related to `StatusBarApp.app`

Possible paths:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/StatusBarApp.app

# for version 5.0 (2016) on Mojave
/Library/Application\ Support/WLAN/StatusBarApp.app/
```

You can close the app by killing the process via the `Activity Monitor` mac app or entering:

```
killall StatusBarApp
```

**Note:** The app will still open next time you restart the Mac

The app is loaded by `launchd` while booting. The related plist should be located at `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and the file name is `Wlan.Software.plist`.

To unload the launch agent enter

```
sudo launchctl unload Wlan.Software
```

To permanently remove the launch agent enter

```
sudo launchctl remove Wlan.Software
```

Alternatively you can remove the file `/Library/LaunchAgents/Wlan.Software.plist`.

After a reboot the icon should be gone.

I have tested this with the installer `TL-WN725N_V2_150901`. Since you didn't specify any adapter (or driver) in your question the name of your app/plist may differ. Please check this with `launchctl list` or `launchctl list | grep -i wlan`.

Comment: My network adaptor is *TL-WN822N Ver 3.0*. `Wlan.Software.plist` can be found at `/Library/LaunchAgents`, but the output of `sudo launchctl unload Wlan.Software.plist` is `/Library/LaunchAgents/Wlan.Software.plist: Could not find specified service`.

Comment: I removed `Wlan.Software.plist` and rebooted my computer, the icon has gone...

Comment: @user3824053 Sorry, copy and paste error ;-). Just remove the .plist part in the `sudo lauchctl ...`command. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It does work, thx for your help. :)

Answer (score 10):

Just alt + click(left) and uninstall option appears.

Comment: easy and quick: this should be the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4):

in macOS Big Sur

```
Option + Left(Single) Click
```

*On a Macintosh, the Alt key is called the Option key*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you still have the driver installer zip from DLink, there should be an Uninstaller package in the archive. I had the drivers for the DWA-192 wireless adapter and was able to fix the same issue you were having with the icon by running `Uninstall.pkg`. This should also remove other specific driver files that were copied during initial installation.

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the driver from d-link (in my case it was https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/products/go-usb-n150-wireless-n-150-easy-usb-adapter?revision=deu_revb#downloads). The zip file includes both the install and the uninstall package, so i ran the uninstall and voila. icon and driver are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can ALT+click on the menubar item and an "uninstall" option will appear. worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -3):

use cleanmymac 3 for remove te menubar icon

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.